# Angular 2 : Remove class if root route not active

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I only understood how to remove a whole element with `*ngIf` , for a specific route that is.

Lets say I have a class applied to an element of my app (header) only for `routerLink="/"`, meaning if I switch to `"/other-page"`, I need the header to lose that class.

How can I achieve this?

How can I link `[ngClass]` to the route change?

**Code:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutService } from 'app/core/services/layout.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'header-main',
    template: `

    <header class="header-main"
        [ngClass]="{'transparent' : isMenuShown}" #header>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact: true}" class="logo">
                <img src="../../../assets/images/logo_dark.svg" alt="{{logoAlt}}" title="{{logoAlt}}">
            </a>
            <a (click)="menuToggle($event)" class="nav-trigger" #navTrigger>
                <i class="icon icon-menu" (click)="isMenuShown = !isMenuShown;"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav class="sub-nav" [ngClass]="{'shown' : isMenuShown}">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">about us</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">team</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">work</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="lets-talk" [ngClass]="{'white' : isMenuShown}">
            <a href="#" class="talk-link">
            <i class="icon icon-talk"></i>
            <p class="link-text">let's talk</p>
            </a>
        </div>

    </header>

    <main-menu (click)="onMenuSelect()" [ngClass]="{'menuShown': isMenuShown}" #mainMenu></main-menu>
`
})


export class HeaderMainComponent {

    @Input() logoAlt: string;
    @Input() logoTitle: string;

    @ViewChild('navTrigger') navTrigger: ElementRef;

    isMenuShown: false;

    constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    menuToggle(event: any) {
          if (this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.contains('opened')) {
        this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.remove('opened');
        } else {
            this.navTrigger.nativeElement.classList.add('opened');
        }
    }

    onMenuSelect(event: any) {
       this.isMenuShown = false;
       this.menuToggle(event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html) directive.

This directive allows you to add or remove a class to an element, based on whether a particular route is active or not.

In your situation, you'll probably also want to make use of `routerLinkActiveOptions` being set to `{exact: true}`, since you won't want your class added when the '/' route is active.

**EDIT:**

From your update, you're not setting routerLinkOptions correctly.

**Your code example:**

```
  <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact: true}" class="logo">
```

**You need to change it to:**

```
 <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="logo">
```

Note the use of the square brackets to indicate that you want to bind the routerLinkActiveOptions input to an object. When you leave out the square brackets, Angular assumes that you want to bind routerLinkActiveOptions to the string `"{exact: true}"`

*(Basically, Angular translates `routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact: true}"` to  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="'{exact: true}'" - which is definitely not what you want.)*

Comment: The problem is, my header is a shared component, and it has `<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" class="logo">` for its logo, but the `active` class remains no matter the page.

Comment: That's where the routerLinkActiveOptions comes in. You'll want to specify {exact:true} so that the current URL must exactly match the routerLink for the active class to be applied. Without that option, the current route just has to be a a parent route (and '/' is the parent of everything)

Comment: I have specified the `exact:true` option, but it doesn't seem to react with it.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you tried for the routerLinkOptions?

Comment: Just did the changes in the code, still no luck, I am in another route, not `/` and the class that I have added in `routerLinkActive="active rootClass"` still exists.

Comment: you included the square brackets around routerLinkActive?

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is not aware of the current route. And in my original question, I wanted to add/remove a class to the header, not the button itself. But one thing leads to another.. so if you have any ideas left, please share. Thanks!

Comment: <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="logo"> resolved my problem. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's really weird that the `routerLinkActive` and `routerLinkActiveOptions` combination did not work for you... what you're describing is the exact use case for them.

But barring that, you can take a longer approach. The `Router` service has a method `isActive` that can also be used to test if a given URL is currently active. *(It also takes a second boolean argument to indicate whether to test for an exact url match or a partial - you'll want to have the second argument as true.)*

Of course, this method is a one-time check - you have to call it every time you want to check - but by tying it into the change detection, you can have Angular call it for you.

So, I'd change your component to:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutService } from 'app/core/services/layout.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'header-main',
    template: `

    <header class="header-main"
        [ngClass]="{'transparent' : isMenuShown}" #header
        [class.active]="isRootActive()"
    >
 ......
`
})
export class HeaderMainComponent {

......

    constructor(
      private layoutService: LayoutService, 
      private renderer: Renderer,  // <!-- you can probably get rid of this with proper use of binding
      private router: Router
   ) { }

  .....

    isRootActive() {
      // returns true if the current route is exactly '/'
      return this.router.isActive('/', true);
    }

}
```

So, on the header component, I can (indirectly) bind the active class (`[class.active]`) to the router's `isActive` method. That way, whenever change detection occurs, the class on the header component will reflect the router's current state.

That should get you want you need.

(It's still weird that routerLinkActive can't accomplish what you want, but without seeing the actual implementation, I can't say what's going wrong.

Looking at the rest of your class, though - i'm pretty sure that you can simplify it a bit by proper use of binding. In particular, I don't think you need the renderer to toggle a class on and off - you can use a similar technique to the one you gonna use with the header.

Anyway, i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">Home</a>
```

you could add `[routerLinkActive]="['your-class-name']"` attribute to your link with Angular Route

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am using angular version 2 (`angular-cli`).